# JNA access to 64-bit DLL (Windows7 64-bit)

Tags: java, dll, 64-bit, jna

Could you please advice. I have simple DLL (under Windows 7 64-bit) and simple Java code with JNA access to this DLL.
The problem is when I use 64-bit version of this DLL looks like I can't get parameter from Java in my DLL test function **giveIntGetInt**, and I have no problem when I use 32-bit DLL.
Where I was wrong?
Thank you!

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;

/** Simple example of native library declaration and usage. */
public class HelloWorld {
    public interface simpleDLL extends Library {
        simpleDLL INSTANCE = (simpleDLL) Native.loadLibrary(
            (Platform.isWindows() ? "simpleDLL" : "simpleDLLLinuxPort"), simpleDLL.class);
         int giveIntGetInt(int a);               // int giveIntGetInt(int a);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     int b = simpleDLL.INSTANCE.giveIntGetInt(2);
     System.out.println("Hello, World\n");

     System.out.println(String.format("Argument %d", b));

    }
}
```

this is C dll method:

```
int simpleDLL::giveIntGetInt(int a)
    {
        return 2*a;
    }
```

For example, this is I've got with 64-bit dll:

```
Hello, World 
Argument 181140
```

32-bit dll:

```
Hello, World 
Argument 4
```

Comment: Stupid question, are you using a 64bit JVM/JDK?

Comment: Yes, I am. I have used jre7 64-bit and 32-bit as well.

Comment: Is the result compeletly random, or it is constant with fixed parameter? Do you always get "181140" as a result when you pass "2" as a parameter? Do you get different results for different parameters?

Comment: The result is the same, with different value of parameter **a**. I also modified code  for giveIntGetInt function to see what I got in this parameter, an in output file I always see "-2147393078".
`int simpleDLL::giveIntGetInt(int a)
 {
  //a = 22;
  FILE *stream;
  if ((stream = fopen("g:\\TEST.dat", "wt ")) == NULL) 
   return 0;
  fprintf (stream, "%d\n",a);
  fclose(stream);

  return 2*a;
 }`

Comment: Problems still actual for me.